# Как добавить атрибут через css

Tags: html, css

Хочу добавить атрибут translate="no" к классу.Как это сделать через css?

Есть класс .main-text

```
.main-text {
    color:red;
    font-weight:900;  
}
```

Как к этому классу добавить атрибут translate="no"?

Comment: Раз вы не показываете, куда хотите добавить, то предполагаю, что вам надо в файле, найти нужный класс и туда добавить нужную вам строчку. Либо префразируйте ваш вопрос, добавив больше информации и привидите пример

Comment: Да,мне нужно найти нужный класс и туда добавить атрибут

Comment: Щас по другому сделаю вопрос тогда

Comment: @SwaD вопрос изменил

Comment: ни как - вообще ни как - css это каскадные таблицы стилей - добавить что то кудато нужен язык скриптов

Comment: Как тогда это сделать через js?

Comment: @MonkeyMutant через js же можно?

Comment: Напишите код пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо добавить какой то аттрибут в какой то блок то просто не обходим язык скриптов, это удобно сделать на javascript и при событии загрузки документа то есть [window.onload](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded) или же весь список подобных событий по сслке мы добавляем аттрибут то есть [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) и конечные код выглядит вот так:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector(".main-text").setAttribute("translate", "no");
};
```

```html
<div class="main-text"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проверить в действии можно вызвав контекстное меню и приверить через [инспектор элементов](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWATDmVdEYw&ab_channel=%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%D0%90%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

Comment: это точно правильно?Я хочу этот код выполнить в консоли chrome разработчика,ничего не случается

Comment: @АндрейНикитин вот прям на SO можете выполнить, просто нажмите Запустить

Comment: @АндрейНикитин если таких блоков много то надо перебрать, я использовал forEach и присвоить результату тот же самый аттрибут, вот так: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/MWBYPPb

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!